# Provide fake metadata to Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I am planning to use Roslyn for a custom project type that uses C# syntax. The code will not be compiled to assemblies, but to a custom format, and the result will not run on any CLR. Some of the simple editor features work just fine.

Now I would still like to use the intellisense and error reporting features of Roslyn as much as possible. My understanding is that these features are built from the ground up to support either C# source code, which I have, or .NET assemblies, which I don't have. So I figured I might be able to provide Roslyn with my custom metadata in such a way that the Roslyn infrastructure can still treat it as a normal assembly reference.

I looked through the source code, but I just couldn't find the right place to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can't you create .Net reference assemblies for your "fake" metadata?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to take a look at the [MetadataReference](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/MetadataReference/MetadataReference.cs) class.  This is what provides metadata to the roslyn services.  Creating your own subclass here is where I would start.

Comment: But that probably wouldn't be any easier than simply creating an assembly; you'll still need standard CLI Metadata.